# What is the distinction between spooling and device queue?

Tags: operating-system

I know that each device has its own device queue. Also i see that "Spooling is a type of buffering. The most common spooling application is print spooling, which places a task (or 'print job') into a queue for extended or later processing."

Does that mean the device queue is spooling? I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

**Spooling** is referred to as [buffered queueing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spooling). A spooler is a logical device that takes input from a quicker process (such as a word processor or image application) and holds that data in a buffered queue for a slower process (printing or some other slow process). The spool allows the quicker application to not have to wait on the slower process to finish before moving on to other tasks.

Spoolers can also be used in reverse so that a slower process is an input and the spool manages the input and holds it in the buffered queue along with a queue of actions until enough data is present to take the actions on the data. This is known as [batch processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing). These reverse spools allow for the data processing actions to be spooled along with the incoming data to be processed when the correct data is present and allows the application that requested the spooling to continue on to other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Device queue is more specific term which take into account about a specific device.you cannot talk about device queue without having an actual device whereas spooling is a generic term that corresponds to usage of disk space as buffer irrespective of the type of device.